# #1241 Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Tags: mysql

Здравствуйте. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно сделать запрос? Делаю

```
update catalog
    set catalog.id_cat = case when catalog.id_cat_1s = ""
        then "0" else (select id, idp_1c from catalog as t1 where 
            t1.idp_1c = catalog.id_cat_1s) end
where catalog.id >= 1 and catalog.id < 500;
```

и вываливается ошибка #1241 Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Если делаю вот такой запрос

```
UPDATE catalog
left JOIN catalog AS table1
    ON catalog.id_cat_1s = table1.idp_1c
       COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci
SET catalog.id_cat = case when catalog.id_cat_1s = ""
    then "0" else table1.id end
where catalog.id >= 1 and catalog.id < 500;
```

то все отрабатывает нормально. Возможно ли сделать такое без join'ов, т.к. с join'ом запрос обрабатывает где-то 10 000 строк и делает это 15 минут, уж как-то долго? Или может подскажете другой метод, чтоб делать это быстрее?

UPD: решение:

```
update catalog
    set catalog.id_cat = case when catalog.id_cat_1s = "" then "0" 
        else (select id from
            (select id, idp_1c from catalog) as t1
            where t1.idp_1c = catalog.id_cat_1s)
    end;
```

В итоге выполнение запроса с 15 минут снизилось до 658мс. (10175 rows affected in 658ms)

Comment: а зачем вам в под запросе `idp_1c ` возвращать ?

Comment: в принципе незачем, но если убрать idp_1c, то ошибка становится "[1093] You can't specify target table 'catalog' for update in FROM clause"

Comment: Вот вроде мелочь на счет idp_1c, но натолкнули на мысль, спасибо! :)
Решение вышло такое

    `update catalog
        set catalog.id_cat = case when catalog.id_cat_1s = ""
            then "0" else (select id from (select id, idp_1c from catalog) as 
                t1  where t1.idp_1c = catalog.id_cat_1s) end;`

Как итог 10175 rows affected in 658ms

Comment: idp_1c - это не мелочь. вы хотите присвоить одному столбцу сразу значение из двух...

Comment: Это верно. Мелочь я имею в виду, что не обратил на это внимание сразу, а со стороны когда народ посмотрел это оказалось очевидной ошибкой.

Answer (score 1):

А почему не просто

```
UPDATE catalog AS t0
LEFT JOIN (SELECT id, idp_1c FROM catalog) AS t1 ON t1.idp_1c = t0.id_cat_1s
SET t0.id_cat = COALESCE(t1.id,0)
```

?

**UPD:** И правда, зачем нам подзапрос?

```
UPDATE catalog AS t0
LEFT JOIN catalog t1 ON t1.idp_1c = t0.id_cat_1s
SET t0.id_cat = COALESCE(t1.id,0)
```

Само собой желательно наличие индексов по idp_1c (ещё лучше, наверное - по (idp_1c,id)) и id_cat_1s

Comment: Ваш запрос тоже отрабатывается, но вот как запустил его так он еще и идет. Подозреваю закончится теперь тоже где-то через минут 15. В общем верный, но долгий.

Comment: 10175 rows affected in 16m 51s 607ms :((

Comment: Тогда упростим... обновлено.

Comment: Тоже медленно. 10175 rows affected in 16m 19s 770ms